# How to initialize and use many similar Jbuttons with less lines of code?

Tags: java, loops, dry

me and my friend are currently writing a memory game as our final assignment for our first programing course. We were wondering if there was another way to initialize our Jbuttons and their properties in a better way with less number of lines, in some kind of loop form. In general we need to make this code more efficient, any tips are much appreciated :)

Easy Level Class:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JMenu;
    import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
    import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.JTextPane;
    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    class EasyWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener {
        JLabel Score = new JLabel("Score: - ");


    JLabel Welcome = new JLabel("Welcome " + StartWindow.user + "!");

    ImageIcon Back = new ImageIcon("mback.png");
    ImageIcon musicicon = new ImageIcon("musicicon.png");
    ImageIcon themeicon = new ImageIcon("themeicon.png");
    ImageIcon difficultyicon = new ImageIcon("difficulty.png");
    ImageIcon pointsicon = new ImageIcon("pointsicon.png");
    ImageIcon studentsicon = new ImageIcon("studentsicon.png");

    JButton AnOtherLevel = new JButton(
            "Click here if you want to change level.");
    JButton Quit = new JButton("Quit Game!");

    JButton Button0 = new JButton(Back);
    JButton Button1 = new JButton(Back);
    JButton Button2 = new JButton(Back);
    JButton Button3 = new JButton(Back);
    JButton Button4 = new JButton(Back);
    JButton Button5 = new JButton(Back);
    JButton Button6 = new JButton(Back);
    JButton Button7 = new JButton(Back);
    JButton Button8 = new JButton(Back);
    JButton Button9 = new JButton(Back);
    JButton Button10 = new JButton(Back);
    JButton Button11 = new JButton(Back);
    JButton Button12 = new JButton(Back);
    JButton Button13 = new JButton(Back);
    JButton Button14 = new JButton(Back);
    JButton Button15 = new JButton(Back);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu Settings = new JMenu("Settings");
    JMenu Theme = new JMenu("Theme");
    JMenu Rules = new JMenu("Rules");
    JMenu Creators = new JMenu("Creators");

    JMenuItem Music = new JMenuItem("Music", musicicon);

    JMenuItem Celebrities = new JMenuItem("Celebrities", themeicon);
    JMenuItem Cities = new JMenuItem("Cities", themeicon);
    JMenuItem Memes = new JMenuItem("Memes", themeicon);

    JMenuItem Difficulty = new JMenuItem("Difficulty", difficultyicon);
    JMenuItem Points = new JMenuItem("Points", pointsicon);

    JMenuItem Ava = new JMenuItem("Ava Baghchesara", studentsicon);
    JMenuItem Michelle = new JMenuItem("Michelle Bill", studentsicon);

    static int[] cardChecker = new int[2];
    static int[] card = new int[9];
    int[] StoreCards = new int[16];
    int[] Button = new int[2];

    static int flipped = 0;
    static int score = 0;
    static int seconds = 0;

    String imageType = ".png";
    String back = ".png";

    JPanel Top = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1, 5, 15));
    JPanel Center = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 5, 5));
    JPanel Bottom = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
    JPanel Right = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 0, 0));
    JPanel Left = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));

    static Container contentArea;

    public EasyWindow() {
        super("User: " + StartWindow.user + " || Easy Level");
        setSize(600, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);

        AnOtherLevel.addActionListener(this);
        Quit.addActionListener(this);

        AnOtherLevel.addMouseListener(this);
        Quit.addMouseListener(this);

        Button0.addActionListener(this);
        Button1.addActionListener(this);
        Button2.addActionListener(this);
        Button3.addActionListener(this);
        Button4.addActionListener(this);
        Button5.addActionListener(this);
        Button6.addActionListener(this);
        Button7.addActionListener(this);
        Button8.addActionListener(this);
        Button9.addActionListener(this);
        Button10.addActionListener(this);
        Button11.addActionListener(this);
        Button12.addActionListener(this);
        Button13.addActionListener(this);
        Button14.addActionListener(this);
        Button15.addActionListener(this);

        AnOtherLevel.setBackground(Color.white);
        AnOtherLevel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        Quit.setBackground(Color.white);
        Quit.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        Button0.setBackground(Color.white);
        Button1.setBackground(Color.white);
        Button2.setBackground(Color.white);
        Button3.setBackground(Color.white);
        Button4.setBackground(Color.white);
        Button5.setBackground(Color.white);
        Button6.setBackground(Color.white);
        Button7.setBackground(Color.white);
        Button8.setBackground(Color.white);
        Button9.setBackground(Color.white);
        Button10.setBackground(Color.white);
        Button11.setBackground(Color.white);
        Button12.setBackground(Color.white);
        Button13.setBackground(Color.white);
        Button14.setBackground(Color.white);
        Button15.setBackground(Color.white);

        add(Top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(Left, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(Center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(Right, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(Bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        Welcome.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        Welcome.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Welcome.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Top.add(Welcome);
        Top.setBackground(Color.white);

        Center.add(Button0);
        Center.add(Button1);
        Center.add(Button2);
        Center.add(Button3);
        Center.add(Button4);
        Center.add(Button5);
        Center.add(Button6);
        Center.add(Button7);
        Center.add(Button8);
        Center.add(Button9);
        Center.add(Button10);
        Center.add(Button11);
        Center.add(Button12);
        Center.add(Button13);
        Center.add(Button14);
        Center.add(Button15);

        Center.setBackground(Color.white);
        Right.setBackground(Color.white);

        Right.add(Score);
        Right.add(Timer);

        Bottom.add(AnOtherLevel);
        Bottom.add(Quit);
        Bottom.setBackground(Color.white);

        contentArea = getContentPane();
        contentArea.add("North", Top);
        contentArea.add("Center", Center);
        contentArea.add("South", Bottom);

        menuBar.add(Settings);
        menuBar.add(Rules);
        menuBar.add(Creators);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        Music.addActionListener(this);

        Theme.addActionListener(this);
        Celebrities.addActionListener(this);
        Cities.addActionListener(this);
        Memes.addActionListener(this);

        Difficulty.addActionListener(this);
        Points.addActionListener(this);

        Ava.addActionListener(this);
        Michelle.addActionListener(this);

        Settings.add(Music);
        Settings.add(Theme);

        Theme.add(Celebrities);
        Theme.add(Cities);
        Theme.add(Memes);

        Rules.add(Difficulty);
        Rules.add(Points);

        Creators.add(Ava);
        Creators.add(Michelle);

        Game();

        setContentPane(contentArea);
        contentArea.setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public void Game() {
        int number = 0;
        int x = 0;

        ImageIcon image[] = new ImageIcon[15];

        while (x < 16) {
            number = (int) RandomNumbers.GetRandomNumber(8);
            image[number] = new ImageIcon(number + imageType);

            if (card[number] < 2) {
                card[number]++;

                StoreCards[x] = number;
                System.out.println(number + " Number" + "card nr " + x);
                x++;

            }

        }

    }

    public void Reset() {
        if (flipped > 2) {
            flipped = 0;

            Button0.setIcon(Back);
            Button1.setIcon(Back);
            Button2.setIcon(Back);
            Button3.setIcon(Back);
            Button4.setIcon(Back);
            Button5.setIcon(Back);
            Button6.setIcon(Back);
            Button7.setIcon(Back);
            Button8.setIcon(Back);
            Button9.setIcon(Back);
            Button10.setIcon(Back);
            Button11.setIcon(Back);
            Button12.setIcon(Back);
            Button13.setIcon(Back);
            Button14.setIcon(Back);
            Button15.setIcon(Back);

        }

    }

    public void Check(int number) {
        if (cardChecker[0] == cardChecker[1]) {
            score = score + 2;
            Score.setText("Score: " + score);
            DisableButtons();

        } else {
            System.out.println("jj");
        }
        if (score == 16) {
            setVisible(false);
            new EndWindow1();
        }
    }

    public void Card1and2(int number, int button) {
        if (flipped == 0) {
            cardChecker[0] = number;
            Button[0] = button;
        }
        if (flipped == 1) {
            cardChecker[1] = number;
            Button[1] = button;

            if (StoreCards[cardChecker[0]] == StoreCards[cardChecker[1]]) {
                if (Button[0] != Button[1])
                    Check(number);
            }

        }

    }

    public void DisableButtons() {
        if (Button[0] == 0 || Button[1] == 0) {
            Button0.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Button[0] == 1 || Button[1] == 1) {
            Button1.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Button[0] == 2 || Button[1] == 2) {
            Button2.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Button[0] == 3 || Button[1] == 3) {
            Button3.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Button[0] == 4 || Button[1] == 4) {
            Button4.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Button[0] == 5 || Button[1] == 5) {
            Button5.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Button[0] == 6 || Button[1] == 6) {
            Button6.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Button[0] == 7 || Button[1] == 7) {
            Button7.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Button[0] == 8 || Button[1] == 8) {
            Button8.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Button[0] == 9 || Button[1] == 9) {
            Button9.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Button[0] == 10 || Button[1] == 10) {
            Button10.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Button[0] == 11 || Button[1] == 11) {
            Button11.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Button[0] == 12 || Button[1] == 12) {
            Button12.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Button[0] == 13 || Button[1] == 13) {
            Button13.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Button[0] == 14 || Button[1] == 14) {
            Button14.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Button[0] == 15 || Button[1] == 15) {
            Button15.setVisible(false);
        }
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        if (event.getSource() == AnOtherLevel) {
            setVisible(false);
            new AnOtherWindow();

        }

        if (event.getSource() == Quit) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if (event.getSource() == Button0) {

            int number = StoreCards[0];
            Button0.setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

            Card1and2(number, 0);

            flipped++;
            Reset();

        }
        if (event.getSource() == Button1) {

            int number = StoreCards[1];
            Button1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

            Card1and2(number, 1);

            flipped++;
            Reset();

        }
        if (event.getSource() == Button2) {
            int number = StoreCards[2];
            Button2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

            Card1and2(number, 2);

            flipped++;
            Reset();
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Button3) {
            int number = StoreCards[3];
            Button3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

            Card1and2(number, 3);

            flipped++;
            Reset();
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Button4) {
            int number = StoreCards[4];
            Button4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

            Card1and2(number, 4);

            flipped++;
            Reset();
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Button5) {
            int number = StoreCards[5];
            Button5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

            Card1and2(number, 5);

            flipped++;
            Reset();
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Button6) {
            int number = StoreCards[6];
            Button6.setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

            Card1and2(number, 6);

            flipped++;
            Reset();
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Button7) {
            int number = StoreCards[7];
            Button7.setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

            Card1and2(number, 7);

            flipped++;
            Reset();
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Button8) {
            int number = StoreCards[8];
            Button8.setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

            Card1and2(number, 8);

            flipped++;
            Reset();
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Button9) {
            int number = StoreCards[9];
            Button9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

            Card1and2(number, 9);

            flipped++;
            Reset();
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Button10) {
            int number = StoreCards[10];
            Button10.setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));
            Card1and2(number, 10);

            flipped++;
            Reset();
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Button11) {
            int number = StoreCards[11];
            Button11.setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

            Card1and2(number, 11);

            flipped++;
            Reset();
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Button12) {
            int number = StoreCards[12];
            Button12.setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + ".png"));

            Card1and2(number, 12);

            flipped++;
            Reset();
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Button13) {
            int number = StoreCards[13];
            Button13.setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

            Card1and2(number, 13);

            flipped++;
            Reset();
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Button14) {
            int number = StoreCards[14];
            Button14.setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

            Card1and2(number, 14);

            flipped++;
            Reset();
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Button15) {
            int number = StoreCards[15];
            Button15.setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

            Card1and2(number, 15);

            flipped++;
            Reset();
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Celebrities) {
            imageType = "c.png";
            Back = new ImageIcon("ceback.png");
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Cities) {
            imageType = ".jpg";
            Back = new ImageIcon("ciback.png");
        }

        if (event.getSource() == Memes) {
            imageType = ".png";
            Back = new ImageIcon("mback.png");
        }



    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == AnOtherLevel) {
            AnOtherLevel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            AnOtherLevel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        if (event.getSource() == Quit) {
            Quit.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            Quit.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        AnOtherLevel.setBackground(Color.white);
        AnOtherLevel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        Quit.setBackground(Color.white);
        Quit.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    }

public class EasyLevelWindow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EasyWindow win = new EasyWindow();

    }
}
```

Comment: Use an array for your buttons.

Comment: Or a List: both of which will help everywhere; not just initialization. Code that involves variables foo1, foo2 .. fooN should generally be treated as a sequence foo[n]. And any code that requires 'excessive copy and pasting' should be re-evaluated.

Comment: If I create a JButton array like: JButton[] button  = new JButton [15] ; and later use a for loop to initialize: for (int n=0; n<=button.length; n++){
   button[n].setIcon(Back);
   button[n].addActionListener(this);
   button[n].setBackground(Color.white);
   Center.add(button[n]);
  } the I get an error message about those four lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you should put your buttons in an array:

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[15];
```

or a list:

```
List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
```

Then you can use a simple for loop to create the buttons and set their properties:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    buttons[i] = new JButton();
    buttons[i].setIcon(...);
    // ...
}
```

In the comments you mentioned you received an error in the loop. That was due to the fact that you did not actually create the `JButton` objects. When you define the array or the list as seen above, you just create some memory space containing 15 `null` objects. I think that becomes a little clearer when looking at the `List` definition. On these objects you can naturally not call any methods. You still have to explicitly create those 15 `JButtons` as the first step in the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Separate it into several micro-classes. Abstract: Widow could be decomposed into Toolbar, Footer, LeftNavigationPanel(for example).
Then you will do

```
new Footer(this);
```

or

```
new Toolbar(this);
```

or

```
Toolbar.attachTo(this);
```

When in Toolbar you will have :

```
class Toolbar {
    JButton save...
    JButton play..
    JButton remove..

    static attachTo(JFrame frame) {
         attaching to frame these buttons
    }
}
```

You will decompose your code a little bit. And all of your frame's parts would be kinda modules.